# The value of the checkboxes does not change React

Tags: reactjs, input, checkbox, react-hooks

I was doing a filter to my products, at the moment I have two checkboxes, one is the warranty and the other is the installation, I made my onChange method like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
        install: false,
        warranty: false
})

const handleInputChanges = (e) => {
        const { name, type, checked, value } = e.target;
        const eachValue = type === 'checkbox' ? checked : value;

        setData({
            ...data,
            [name]: eachValue
        })
        console.log(data)
}
```

and the inputs are like this:

```
<FormControlLabel
         name="install"
         control={
         <Checkbox
                  name="install"
                  onChange={handleInputChanges}
                  color="primary"
                  value={data.install}
         />
         }
         label="Instalación"
/>
<FormControlLabel
         name="warranty"
         control={
         <Checkbox
                  name="warranty"
                  onChange={handleInputChanges}
                  color="primary"
                  value={data.warranty}
         />
         }
         label="Garantía"
/>
```

The problem is that when I click on the checkboxes the value is not changed, to change it I have to press it twice, but the value does not agree with the checkbox. Example: the checkbox is active (visually), but in the value it returns false and the same thing happens vice versa. This happens for both inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Put the console in outside the of the `handleInputChanges` for the get latest state value

For the best practices `on input Change` event pass the `state name` and `state value` so you can use easily use in `handleChange` function !

Here is my code pls check

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    install: false,
    warranty: false
  })

  const handleInputChanges = (name, value) => {
    setData({ ...data, [name]: value });
  }
  console.log(data)

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControlLabel
        name="install"
        control={
          <Checkbox
            name="install"
            onChange={(e) => handleInputChanges('install', e.target.checked)}
            color="primary"
            value={data.install}
          />
        }
        label="Instalación" />

      <FormControlLabel
        name="warranty"
        control={
          <Checkbox
            name="warranty"
            onChange={(e) => handleInputChanges('warranty', e.target.checked)}
            color="primary"
            value={data.warranty}
          />
        }
        label="Garantía" />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your advice, the code works correctly.

Comment: If my answer help you. Accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not access the old state directly when updating the state like this:

```
setData({
   ...data,
   [name]: eachValue
})
```

You better do it this way instead:

```
setData(data => ({
   ...data,
   [name]: eachValue
}))
```

You can combine my answer with Mr @mayur-vaghasiya's answer.

Comment: thanks for the help, and as you said, both codes work fine.

Comment: @YCrhis Good to know. Now it's good to set the question as answered.